# Can somebody explain this piece of clojure code?

Tags: clojure

I am learning clojure and I am having problem understanding this clojure code, so I have this partial function

```
 (def add-five (partial + 5))
```

When I run,

```
(add-five 2)# I get 7
(add-five 2 5) # I get 12
```

For first, I give one argument; For second, I give two arguments.

```
(map add-five [1 2 3 4 5])
```

this gives me

```
(6 7 8 9 10)
```

Here, I am assuming, add-five is being applied element of the list. However when I run,

```
(reduce add-five [1 2 3 4 5])
```

, I have no idea what is happening?

```
 (reduce add-five [0]) #gives me zero
 (reduce add-five [0 0]) #gives me five
```

Can someone explain what happens what I run the reduce like above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 (reduce add-five [0]) #gives me zero
```

For this line this rule from [the documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) is applied:

> If coll has only 1 item, it is returned and f is not called

Otherwise it applies the `add-five` function to `0` and `0` arguments: `(add-five 0 0)`